# Errors When Trying to start Apache 2.4.37

Tags: apache, svn, rhel

I'm running into some difficulties getting Apache to run on RHEL 8. It's a new instance to support an SVN upgrade as the old server we inherited is very out of date and not compliant. I copied the config from the old environment and ironed out most of the errors, but I'm getting the below in the error log:

```
[Wed May 10 14:03:56.430759 2023] [core:notice] [pid 4483] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed May 10 14:03:56.432320 2023] [suexec:notice] [pid 4483] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed May 10 14:03:56.461205 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4483] AH00163: Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.1.1k SVN/1.10.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 10 14:03:56.461261 2023] [core:notice] [pid 4483] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed May 10 14:05:26.429869 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4483] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

I looked into some of the previous solutions such as adding the line the below line to the config (it wasn't present in any form):

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*
```

No change after doing so.

I also tried commenting out the SSLSessionCache as I saw in another post with no luck.

There is no http process running, though before it times out, I can at least hit the redhat landing page briefly when navigating to the IP in the browser.

Edit: Made the adjustment to from the answer below but still getting some issues, possibly cert related:

```
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.962326 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 43202] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.962992 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 43202] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.37 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.37, Library: OpenSSL/1.1.1k
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.963031 2023] [suexec:notice] [pid 43202] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.981305 2023] [ldap:debug] [pid 43202] util_ldap.c(2441): AH01303: LDAP: SSL trusted global cert - /etc/pki/tls/certs/******.crt (type CA_BASE64)
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.981325 2023] [ldap:debug] [pid 43202] util_ldap.c(2604): AH01308: LDAP: SSL verify server certificate - FALSE
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.981858 2023] [ldap:debug] [pid 43202] util_ldap.c(3023): AH01316: LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0x55cacd992888 rmm=0x55cacd992988 for VHOST: ******.****.**
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.982015 2023] [ldap:info] [pid 43202] AH01318: APR LDAP: Built with OpenLDAP LDAP SDK
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.984499 2023] [ldap:info] [pid 43202] AH01319: LDAP: SSL support available
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.984987 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 43202] mod_socache_shmcb.c(401): AH00821: shmcb_init allocated 512000 bytes of shared memory
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.984998 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 43202] mod_socache_shmcb.c(417): AH00822: for 511912 bytes (512000 including header), recommending 32 subcaches, 88 indexes each
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.985002 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 43202] mod_socache_shmcb.c(450): AH00824: shmcb_init_memory choices follow
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.985006 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 43202] mod_socache_shmcb.c(452): AH00825: subcache_num = 32
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.985010 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 43202] mod_socache_shmcb.c(454): AH00826: subcache_size = 15992
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.985014 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 43202] mod_socache_shmcb.c(456): AH00827: subcache_data_offset = 2128
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.985018 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 43202] mod_socache_shmcb.c(458): AH00828: subcache_data_size = 13864
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.985022 2023] [socache_shmcb:debug] [pid 43202] mod_socache_shmcb.c(460): AH00829: index_num = 88
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.985163 2023] [socache_shmcb:info] [pid 43202] AH00830: Shared memory socache initialised
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.985171 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 43202] AH01887: Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.985739 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 43202] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.37 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.37, Library: OpenSSL/1.1.1k
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.992422 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 43202] AH00163: Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.1.1k SVN/1.10.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.992441 2023] [mpm_prefork:info] [pid 43202] AH00164: Server built: Mar 28 2023 09:01:53
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.992455 2023] [core:notice] [pid 43202] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.992459 2023] [core:debug] [pid 43202] log.c(1571): AH02639: Using SO_REUSEPORT: yes (1)
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.992463 2023] [mpm_prefork:debug] [pid 43202] prefork.c(919): AH00165: Accept mutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.993273 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43204] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.993307 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43204] proxy_util.c(1999): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.993332 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43204] proxy_util.c(2050): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 43204 for (*)
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.997414 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43205] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.997446 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43205] proxy_util.c(1999): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Thu May 11 08:10:35.997471 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43205] proxy_util.c(2050): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 43205 for (*)
[Thu May 11 08:10:36.000390 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43206] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Thu May 11 08:10:36.000428 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43206] proxy_util.c(1999): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Thu May 11 08:10:36.000457 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43206] proxy_util.c(2050): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 43206 for (*)
[Thu May 11 08:10:36.000948 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43207] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Thu May 11 08:10:36.000982 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43207] proxy_util.c(1999): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Thu May 11 08:10:36.001005 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43207] proxy_util.c(2050): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 43207 for (*)
[Thu May 11 08:10:36.002280 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43208] proxy_util.c(1939): AH00925: initializing worker proxy:reverse shared
[Thu May 11 08:10:36.002313 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43208] proxy_util.c(1999): AH00927: initializing worker proxy:reverse local
[Thu May 11 08:10:36.002337 2023] [proxy:debug] [pid 43208] proxy_util.c(2050): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 43208 for (*)
[Thu May 11 08:12:06.130122 2023] [core:info] [pid 43202] AH00096: removed PID file /etc/httpd/run/httpd.pid (pid=43202)
[Thu May 11 08:12:06.130189 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 43202] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
```

Answer (score 0):

Error log says "SELinux policy enabled"
So if you cannot setup an SELinux role for Apache you may need to disable it.

To disable SELinux in runtime run the command:

```
setenforce 0
```

To disable it permanently (across reboots)
Edit the file:

```
/etc/selinux/config
```

Change the line:

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

To:

```
SELINUX=Disabled
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated that and it removed the selinux issue, though the other lines remain. I tried a few other things (increase read permissions levels, pulling over a ldap .conf file from the other server) but still can't seem to get it off the ground.

I added some additional logging and I think it might be a cert issue? Added extra logs to the original post